# application to make shell typing easier?

Tags: linux

I wonder if there is any application for the linux bash shell to make it more easier to type.

E.g. if I type "c" then maybe it would give me all commands that starts with that letter for example "cd", "cp" etc. then if I type "cd" and press space it give me all the parameters for that command.

is there application of this kind to automatize command typing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There already is such a feature built into bash. Type "c" and press tab. If nothing shows up it's cause it cannot add another letter since there are more options available. Press tab again and it will ask if you want a list of the available commands.

It works for parameters as well as long as the parameter in question is a file or folder name.

Comment: It works for program options as well, if you have bash-completion installed. http://bash-completion.alioth.debian.org/ and you can add your own completions.

Comment: @dennis and @johan-skold. it doesnt work. ive installed bash_completion and ive started it in the shell. but when i type "apt-get up[TAB]" i get nothing. and im sure ive started it.

Comment: Did you press Tab twice?

Comment: @dennis. i pressed it 10 times=) im using ubuntu server btw

Comment: @ajsie: What do these commands give you? `echo $BASH_VERSION` and `bind -p | grep complet` and `shopt -p progcomp`

Answer (score 1):

You may prefer setting the completion type to "menu-complete". In your `~/.inputrc` file you can add a line that says `"\C-i": menu-complete` or at a Bash prompt, enter `bind '"\C-i":menu-complete'`, then each time you press Tab, it will step through each possible completion.

**Edit:** fixed typo in `bind` command.

Comment: i have no problem with the completion itself. the problem lies in the nature of what words to complete my started letter. when i type eg. "aptitu" and then press TAB TAB it gives me "aptitude, aptitude-run-state-bundle and aptitude-create-state-bundle". when i have typed "aptitude " and then press TAB TAB it gives me the files in current directory. i want to be able to have all the aptitude's parameters listed: install, search, update and so on. is this possible?

Comment: @ajsie: When I type "aptitu[TAB][TAB]" it completes to "aptitude", then I press [space][TAB][TAB] then it gives me a list of `aptitude` commands, such as `autoclean`, `build-dep`, `changelog`, etc. Then I press "i[TAB][TAB]" and now I have `aptitude install`.

Comment: @ajsie: **However**, with `menu-complete`, I type "apti[TAB]" (one [TAB]) and get "aptitude", then I press space (now there are two spaces, one was provided by the completion) and [TAB]. Now I see "aptitude autoclean". Then each time I press [TAB] it cycles through the commands. If instead of the space, I had typed "c" then pressed [TAB] it would cycle between "changelog" and "clean". (By the way, sorry for the typo in my original answer. I've fixed it. Perhaps my error caused it not to work for you.)